# Pass data from one model to another in Backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, backbone.js

```
<form>
  <input id = "one" class = "number">
  <input id = "two" class = "number">
  <input id = "three" class = "number">
  <input id = "four" class = "number">
</form>
```

in a model.

I have a button which has the following function:

```
$("#button").click(function(){
  var mynumber = $("#one").val() + $("#two").val() + $("#three").val();
  //IF i do a this.model.save here it will POST all four fields that I dont want
});
```

Question: I want to create a new model which gets this value mynumber and do a POST request. So far I have this:

```
var mymodel = Numbermodel.extend({
  this.model.set(mynumber);
  this.model.save({},{
    success: function(model, response) {
      console.log('success! ' + response);
    },
    error: function(model, response) {
      console.log('error! ' + response);
    }
  });
});
```

I am not sure how I can connect these two. I just want to POST mynumber not all the individual fields. Any help would be appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

```
var FormView = Backbone.View.extend({
      tagName: 'form',
      events: {
          'click #button': 'sentRequest'
      },
      initialize: function(){
         ...
      },
      render : function(){
         ...
      },
      sentRequest: function(){
          var mynumber = $("#one").val() + $("#two").val() + $("#three").val();
          var mymodel = new Numbermodel();
           model.set(mynumber);
           model.save({},{
              success: function(model, response) {
                  console.log('success! ' + response);
               },
              error: function(model, response) {
                  console.log('error! ' + response);
              }
          });
          return false;   //return false -- with the code form request does not send 
      }
})
$(function(){
    var view = FormView();
    view.render();

});
```

Use that code with your html code.

Comment: My POST request still contains one, two, three, four and mynumber. Can I destroy the model before setting to mynumber? thank you

Comment: @James add to end `return false` sentRequest